# How to collect string in a file and use it for replacement

Tags: powershell

I'm currently trying to parse a file line by line and use them for instruction replacement.

in my first file called **filein.txt** for instruction have this kind of information (informations on it are not fixed):

```
test 1
test
test 3
test 4
test test 
Mr Test
```

In the second file called **filechg.txt**, I need to replace Characters on it by finding string on file **filein.txt**

The information looks like a CSV :

```
6672;Mr test;Ticket;Off;Active;F;
5948;test 4;Ticket;Off;Active;F;
6672;Mr test;Ticket;Off;Active;F;
5948;test 2;Ticket;Off;Active;F;
6672;Mr test;Ticket;Off;Active;F;
5948;test 6;Ticket;Off;Active;F;
6672;test 7;Ticket;Off;Active;F;
5948;tests;Ticket;Off;Active;F;
6672;Mr test;Ticket;Off;Active;F;
```

By find string, I replace the string ;F; by ;T;

So for that I'm doing this:

```
filechg= 'c:\temp\filechg.txt'
filein= 'c:\temp\filein.txt'

  foreach($line in $filein) { 
     Get-Content $filechg | % {$_ -replace "($line.*)F;", '$1T;'} | Set-Content $filechg
  }
```

It seem's that I'm able to echo in the foreach instruction the variable "line" but not using it for replace instruction.

the response should be:

```
6672;Mr test;Ticket;Off;Active;T;
5948;test 4;Ticket;Off;Active;T;
6672;Mr test;Ticket;Off;Active;T;
5948;test 2;Ticket;Off;Active;T;
6672;Mr test;Ticket;Off;Active;T;
5948;test 6;Ticket;Off;Active;T;
6672;test 7;Ticket;Off;Active;T;
5948;tests;Ticket;Off;Active;T;
6672;Mr test;Ticket;Off;Active;T;
```

Could you help me to solve this problem?

Kind regards

Comment: Use `Import-Csv` instead of `Get-Content`. If you are using `gc` then use `ConvertTo-Csv` along with it. And is `;` part of your data or a `delimiter`?

Comment: the `;` is the delimiter, but in my case, I'm using regex for change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your have to read in file content only, but at least once, what your script doesn't.
And apply all replacements to the read variable, here `$content`

```
$filechg = '.\filechg.txt'
$filein  = '.\filein.txt'

$content = Get-Content $filechg

  foreach($line in (Get-Content $filein)) {
     $content = $content -replace "($line.*)F;", '$1T;'
  }
$content
# $content | Set-Content $filechg
```

Sample display output (uncomment last line to write result to file)

```
6672;Mr test;Ticket;OfT;Active;T;
5948;test 4;Ticket;OfT;Active;T;
6672;Mr test;Ticket;OfT;Active;T;
5948;test 2;Ticket;Off;Active;T;
6672;Mr test;Ticket;OfT;Active;T;
5948;test 6;Ticket;Off;Active;T;
6672;test 7;Ticket;Off;Active;T;
5948;tests;Ticket;Off;Active;T;
6672;Mr test;Ticket;OfT;Active;T;
```

The line `test` from filein renders all other superfluous because this string is present in all lines from filechg. To avoid this include a `;` at the end of the lines in filein.

Comment: I tried to add `;` on each lines and i'm still have the problem, the F on the "OFF" is also replace.. do you have an idea to fix this issue?

Comment: you can anchor the RegEx at the end with a `$` -> `$content = $content -replace "($line.*)F;$", '$1T;'`